# Shift Cipher Gives Funny Characters. Related to ASCII shifting?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int MAXLEN = 50; // max length for input sequence of characters
const int MAXKEY = 10; // max length for key

// Shift Cipher Function. Use of ASCII Table for algorithm. (PROBLEMATIC)
char Shift(char chr, int k)
{
    char c = chr;
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        c = c + k - 32; // For Uppercase
        if (c < 65)
        {
            c = c + 26; // A-1 must be Z
        }
        else if (c > 90)
        {
            c = c - 26; // Z+1 must be A
        }
        return c;
    }
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        c = c + k + 32; // + 32 to convert it to Lower case
        if (c < 97)
        {
            c = c + 26; // a-1 must be z
        }
        else if (c > 122)
        {
            c = c - 26; // z+1 must be a
        }
        return c;
    }
    else
        return c;
}

int main()
{
    // to store user inputs
    char s;            // 'e' for encryption, 'd' for decryption
    char text[MAXLEN]; // the sequence of characters to encrypt/decrypt
    char key[MAXKEY];  // the key
    char c, v, ch;
    int n, cn = 0;

    cin >> s;

    // For the first input
    for (int i = 0; i < 51; ++i)
    {
        cin >> c;
        if (c != '!')
        {
            text[i] = c;
            cn++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // For the second input
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin >> v;
        key[i] = v;
    }

    // Execution
    for (int i = 0; i < 51; ++i)
    {
        if (s == 'd')
        {
            ch = Shift(text[i], -key[i]); // 2->1 Logic
            cout << ch;
        }
        else if (s == 'e')
        {
            ch = Shift(text[i], key[i]);
            cout << ch;
        }
        if (ch != ' ')
        {
            cout << ch;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hi everyone. I am trying to solve a shift cipher problem but I do not know how to deal with the funny character output.

We first consider the algorithm to encrypt/decrypt a single character:
To encrypt (decrypt) a letter c (within the alphabet A-Z or a-z) with a shift of k positions:

1. Let x be c's position in the alphabet (0 based), e.g., the position of B is 1 and position of g is 6.
2. For encryption, calculate y = x + k modulo 26;
   for decryption, calculate y = x − k modulo 26.
3. Let w be the letter corresponding to position y in the alphabet. If c is in
   uppercase, the encrypted (decrypted) letter is w in lowercase; otherwise, the
   encrypted (decrypted) letter is w in uppercase.
   A character which is not within the alphabet A-Z or a-z will remain unchanged under
   encryption or decryption.

Example. Given letter B and k = 3, we have x = 1, y = 1 + 3 mod 26 = 4, and w = E . As B
is in uppercase, the encrypted letter is e .

Now, to encrypt/decrypt a sequence of characters:
The number of positions, k, used to shift a character is determined by a key V of n
characters. For example, if V is a 4-character key 'C', 'O', 'M', 'P', and their positions in the
alphabet is 2, 14, 12 and 15, respectively. To encrypt a sequence of characters, we shift the
first character by +2 positions, the second by +14, the third by +12, the fourth by +15 and
repeat the key, i.e., we shift the fifth character by +2, the sixth by +14, until we encrypt all the
characters in the input sequence.

This is the intended I/O:

Input:

```
e !

3 A B C
```

Output:

```
!
```

But the output is problematic:

```
≡≡↨↨╧╧??÷÷00αα‼‼▓▓╘╘zz☻☻                §§ll??÷÷☺☺
```

So I suspect that the problem is in the Shift function but not the int main() ones. Yet I am not sure how.

Comment: There's a lot of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in that code. Use [the standard functions available](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte) instead.

Comment: Also, the loop `for (int i = 0; i < 51; ++i)` can make you write out of bounds of the `text` array. Since the first loop can break early, there's also the possibility that not all elements in the `text` array will be initialized, which means you later will use its *indeterminate* contents. Using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And by using `key[i]` in the shift-and-print loop, you will definitely go out of bounds of the `key` array.

Comment: Have you asked the question on the problem website's forum?  Looks like this problem is on Chegg, WeCode, LogicProHub (which **sells** the solution to this problem), CourseHero, and StuDocu for the University of Hong Kong.  Otherwise, check out [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).